# Endless loop with try and catch JAVA

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, try-catch

so what I am trying to do is have the user input a valid coordinate in a matrix, that is an INT which is greater than -1,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
int coordinates[] = new int[2];
coordinates[0]=-1;  
coordinates[1]=-1;
boolean check = true;
while (((coordinates[0]<0)||(coordinates[0]>R))  && check) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a valid row number:\t");
    try { 
        coordinates[0]=scanner.nextInt(); 
        break; 
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    }
}
while (((coordinates[1]<0)||(coordinates[1]>C)) && check) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a valid col number:\t");
    try { 
        coordinates[1]=scanner.nextInt(); 
        break; 
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    }       
}
```

the problem is that it loops endlessly after entering a not valid input
int R is the size of the row
int C is the size of the collumn

Comment: that is why i put the break?, so that, i think, the program will get out of the while once the storing is finish

Comment: Why do you even have the check flag?

Comment: also, what is R & C?

Comment: You might wish to clean up this code, the second loop is not needed in the example and R / C is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not handling the error you're catching. 
If you'll provide wrong format of number for the `nextInt()` method, then the `InputMismatchException` will be `thrown`. Then because the `catch` does nothing, the loop will continue (start from begining) and the scanner will read the same incorrect value, and so on...

So instead of this:

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
}
```

Try this:

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Wrong number entered.");
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

This way you'll force `scanner` to move past the last incorrect input.

**EDIT:**

You're loop is also broken because you do `break` after reading the input. In that case if you'll put the negative number you'll `break` as well and won't check the loop condition. Remove the `break` statement and it will work as expected:

```
while (((coordinates[0]<0)||(coordinates[0]>R))  && check) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a valid row number:\t");
    try { 
        coordinates[0]=scanner.nextInt(); 
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("That's not a valid number.");
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

```
public static void main(final String args[])
{
    int maxRowsNumber = 10;
    int maxColsNumber = 10;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    int coordinates[] = new int[2];
    coordinates[0]=-1;  
    coordinates[1]=-1;
    boolean check = true;
    while (((coordinates[0]<0)||(coordinates[0]>maxRowsNumber))  && check) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid row number:\t");
        try { 
            coordinates[0]=scanner.nextInt(); 
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid number.");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    while (((coordinates[1]<0)||(coordinates[1]>maxColsNumber)) && check) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid col number:\t");
        try { 
            coordinates[1]=scanner.nextInt(); 
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid number.");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }       
    }
    System.out.println("Inserted RowsNumber: " + coordinates[0]);
    System.out.println("Inserted RowsNumber: " + coordinates[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a valid row number:    11
Please enter a valid row number:    22
Please enter a valid row number:    10
Please enter a valid col number:    11
Please enter a valid col number:    2
Inserted RowsNumber: 10
Inserted RowsNumber: 2
```

Comment: sir i followed your suggestion now my problem is it accepts negative integers, can you help me with that sir?

Comment: Sure I can, but first you would have to answer questions from comments - what is R&C?

Comment: int R is the size of the row int C is the size of the column, R and C is to be input by the user that will be the size of his desired matrix

Comment: @dumas - edited my asnswer, i hope it will work for you. If so you accept the answer.

Comment: now that i removed the break; it keeps on asking for the user to input a number even if it is valid, sir thank you for helping and for being patient.

Comment: @dumas - it works for me, are you sure you're putting values lower than R&C?

Comment: @dumas - ok. So you're using R & C wrong way because you're using them in a loop. If you've initialized them with 0, then you're loop condition would be never satisfied.
I've edited my answer again and pasted the full main method, so you can look how it works. I've replaced your R&C with maxRowsNumber and maxColsNumber. Your inserted coordinates are in the array - coordinates[0], and coordinates[1] (as shown in the output). Also I don't know what is the `check` variable for - if it's not for future use you can delete it as it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If by "not valid input" you mean "not any kind of integer", then your scanner will fail each time it tries to read another integer, so you'll hit your `catch`, and do nothing to stop the loop.  Maybe you intended to set `check` to `false` in such circumstances?  Or maybe you meant to put the `break` in each `catch`?

Using a `break` when a *valid* integer is read isn't right, because it might be a negative integer, which your loop guard says you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as what your doing, I just tried to improve it a little bit by removing hardcoded values, made variables more descriptive, and included input validations.

```
final int ROW = 0;
final int COL = 1;

int coordinates[] = new int[2];
coordinates[ROW] = -1;
coordinates[COL] = -1;
boolean isInputValid = true;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid row number:\t");
        coordinates[ROW] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        isInputValid = false; //if the input is not int
    }
} while (!isInputValid && (coordinates[ROW] < 0) //do this until the input is an int
        || (coordinates[ROW] > R));              //and it's also not less than 0 or greater than R


//same logic applies here
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid col number:\t");
        coordinates[COL] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        isInputValid = false;
    }
} while (!isInputValid && (coordinates[COL] < 0)
        || (coordinates[COL] > C));
```

Hope this helps.